# jqgrid overflows panel on initial page load in IE 11

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I am using several jqGrids inside bootstrap panels.  Works great in chrome. On initial page load in IE (I'm using 11), the jqGrids are wider than the panels, so they overflow on the right.  If I refresh the page, everything is fine.  I have grids on multiple pages, this only happens on one page.  The difference with this one page is it has a left side (full height) menu.

I assume IE is not rendering the 'autowidth: true' correctly on first try.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="/">MyApp</a></li>
                <li><a href="#manageRequest">Manage Requests</a></li>
                <li><a href="#manageHardware">Manage Hardware</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="panel panel-primary" id="manageRequest">
                <div class="panel panel-heading">Manage Requests</div>
                <div class="panel panel-body">
                    <p class="lead">Click on a request to see available actions</p>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="request-grid"></table>
                    <div id="request-pager"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-success" id="manageHardware">
                <div class="panel panel-heading">Manage Hardware</div>
                <div class="panel panel-body">
                    <p class="lead">Click on a device, then click edit</p>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="hardware-grid"></table>
                    <div id="hardware-pager"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS code for grids:

```
// Request Grid Operations
$("#request-grid").jqGrid({
    url: requestUrl,
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['Request Number', 'Approved?', 'Request Status', 'Employee Name', 'Requested By', 'Request Date'],
    colModel: [
            { name: "RequestId", key: true, sortable: true, search: true, sorttype: 'integer', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'] } },
            { name: "IsApproved" },
            { name: "RequestStatus" },
            { name: "EmployeeName", stype: "text", searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn', 'bw'] } },
            { name: "RequesterEmail" },
            {
                name: "DateCreated", sortable: true, sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat: "m/d/Y" },
                search: false             
            }
    ],
    loadonce: true,
    height: '500',
    autowidth: true, 
    pager: "#request-pager",
    onSelectRow: function (id) {            
        $("#RequestNumber").val(id);
        $("#SelectedRequestModel").modal('show');
    }
});
$("#request-grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#request-pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, view: false, refresh: true }, {},{},{}, { closeAfterSearch: true });


// Hardware Grid Operations
$("#hardware-grid").jqGrid({
    url: hardwareGridUrl,
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['HardwareId', 'Model', 'Type', 'Description', 'Price', 'Mobile Device?'],
    colModel: [
            { name: "HardwareId", key: true, hidden: true },
            { name: "Model", editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
            { name: "ItemType", editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
            { name: "ItemDescription", editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', editoptions: { rows: "5", cols: "25" }, width: 500 },
            { name: "Price", editable: true, formatter: 'currency', align: 'center' },
            { name: "IsMobile", editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: 'true:false' }, editrules: { required: true } },
    ],
    loadonce: true,
    height: '300',
    autowidth: true,
    pager: "#hardware-pager",
    editurl: editHardwareUrl            
});

$("#hardware-grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#hardware-pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, view: false, refresh: true },
        { 
            reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeOnEscape: true, closeAfterEdit: true,
            afterSubmit: function () {
                $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: 'json' });
                return true;
            }
        },
        {
            reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeOnEscape: true, closeAfterAdd: true,
            afterSubmit: function () {
                $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: 'json' });
                return [true, ""];
            }
        },
        {}
);
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? **It's critical to know if you report a problem/bug**. The best would be the demo. There are many places in your code, which I would recommend you to improve. For example, it's important to use `idPrefix` with different value in at least one grid (for example `idPrefix: "g2_"`), bacsue the values of `HardwareId` and `RequestId` could be the same and you will have id duplicates.

Comment: Independent from your final choice of jqGrid, I'd recommend you to verify whether the problem exist with free jqGrid 4.13.2: to edit (temporary) `<link>` and `<script>` which you use to load jqGrid files. You need to use: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.13.2/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">`, `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.13.2/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>` and comment `grid.locale-en.js` or use `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.13.2/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.min.js"></script>`

Comment: **I'd recommend you to verify whether the problem exist with free jqGrid 4.13.2: to edit (temporary) three lines of your HTML code with `<link>` and `<script>` which you use to load jqGrid files.** Is the problem exist in free jqGrid too or it's a bug in Guriddo 4.8.2?

Comment: I tried it in IE with your provided links, the problem still occurs.

Comment: Sorry, but I can help you only with free jqGrid fork. It's alternative fork which I develop starting with renaming jqGrid to Gurrido jqGrid JS and making it commercial (see [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). If you have an interest than you should create the demo which reproduce the problem and which use non-minimized code (`jquery.jqgrid.src.js`). I will analyse the problem and debug it.

Comment: Thanks, but I found the problem.  The grids were in parent divs that used fixed positioning, etc.  Once I removed all the positioning and used bootstrap columns instead, they display fine.  Not sure what the exact problem was, but the jqgrids didn't like something with the positioning.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! Mixing fixed, relative and absolute position in the hierarchy of dives made large problems to almost all existing CSS Frameworks. I removed saving the last opened position of Add/Edit forms from free jqGrid after trying different methods to calculate absolute position of the windows. I'd recommend you to avoid mixing of `position` as far it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue, setting the padding on the containing element seemed to be a decent quick work around.

My Html

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Work Sheet</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="gridContainer" class=panel-body>
        <table id="jqGrid">
        </table>
        <div id="jqGridPager">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```css
#gridContainer {
    padding: 0px 7px 0px 0px;
}
```

For what ever reason it always seemed to flow out the right side. 7px did the trick.